# Unity3d - Dont reload the audioSource when switching scene

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, reload, scene, switching

Simple question but make me blur.

I have an audio source on let say "Main" scene, and I make it DontDestroyOnLoad, which make it could keep playing my audio even i going next scene, let say "Game" scene.

Problem is, when i get back from "Game" scene to "Main" scene, my audio will restart over but not continue playing as i expected. How should i actually script for this?

My current script :

```
void Awake() {
    if (instance != null && instance != this) {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        return;
    } else {
        instance = this;
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: **when i get back from "Game" scene to "Main" scene** how are you loading your scene?

Comment: Is the AudioSource attached to the object you have this script on?

Comment: @UmairM I using SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");

Comment: @Rob yes, i attach on the object in the scene

Answer (score 0):

Simply `Instantiate` you AudioController object if there is no AudioController in the main scene.

```
void Start()
{
 if(GameObject.FindWithTag("AudioController") == NULL)
  {
   Instantiate(AudioController);
  }
}
```

AudioController is the one that will have `DontDestroyOnLoad` and AudioSource in it. This way there will be just one instance.